# Don't understand the space under my images, nothing in my css can change it?

Tags: html, css, image, frontend, masonry

I know the famous probleme about space under images, and currently we can turn off it my adding marin 0 or padding 0, oven with some technique like font-size: 0 when the display inline block is active

but here I doesn't understand why it's still here.
(I put texts under every images to hide it but if I delete the text the image don't touch my border)

do you have an idée ?

for more comprehension of my bad english here is it a Codepen link : https://codepen.io/quentindigital/pen/KKzmXQd

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&display=swap');
    
    *, div, p, img {  
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        background: #ddd;
        }
    
    .css-masonry { 
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-count:4;
        column-count: 4;
        
        -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
        -moz-column-gap: 1em;
        column-gap: 1em;
        
        -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
        -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;    
        column-gap: 1.5em;
        
        margin: 1.5em;    
        padding: 0;
        font-size: .85em;
    }
    
    
    .item {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        
        font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.8em;
        
        background: #fff;
        margin: 0 0 1em;
        width: 100%;
        
        -webkit-transition:1s ease all;
    
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 6px; 
        overflow: hidden; /* to affect the inner elements with the radius */
    }
    
    .item img{ max-width:100%; font-size: 0; height: auto; /* to be sure to don't have a spacing after the img due to the inline block function */ }
    
    .item-number {
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #fff;
        
        
        font-size: 0.8em;
        display: flex; /* flex is for center verticaly and horizontaly the number */
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 0 2px 2px 0; /* I display right and bottom padding because of the font who is not center par default : delete if you change the font */
        
        position: absolute;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    
    .item .title {
        border: 0px solid blue;
        padding: 10px 10px 14px;
    }
    
    .french {color: grey; font-size: 0.8em;}
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
        .css-masonry {
            -moz-column-count: 1;
            -webkit-column-count: 1;
            column-count: 1;
        }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 421px) and (max-width: 768px){
        .css-masonry {
            -moz-column-count: 2;
            -webkit-column-count: 2;
            column-count: 2;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1000px){
        .css-masonry {
            -moz-column-count: 3;
            -webkit-column-count: 3;
            column-count: 3;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
        .css-masonry {
            -moz-column-count: 4;
            -webkit-column-count: 4;
            column-count: 4;
        }
    } </style>
<!-- container all the item -->
<div class="css-masonry">
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">1</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/36995178_263875847529942_2246967554570452992_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=EnzHOjtds68AX8gg96p&oh=7ce1e58fa146ed92c493dcfac19c74d7&oe=5F714385">
    <!-- title if title -->  
    <div class="title">
        This is a pure CSS only responsive masonry grid.
        <p class="french">Un grid masonry en pure css</p>
      </div>
  </div>
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">2</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/75372356_454280415162174_4260765077873658199_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=Nvnwmo7pSLYAX_Sqb7Z&oh=4fea9949444468de1d84affb1b0bbb72&oe=5F701D00">
        <div class="title">
        Copenhagen
      </div>  
  </div>
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">3</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/67585759_101041704524588_7115246159420840627_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=n13JSRJuSO4AX-Yru9Q&oh=cab36a1bcbad96a7dc0495f6ad24563b&oe=5F705AB4">
       <div class="title">
           <a href="instagram.com/quentinrenaux" target="_blank">Visit my instagram</a>
      </div>    
  </div>
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">4</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/116910670_636321583927860_1186986929814598848_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=ImTKV8mCBkUAX_wBVuR&oh=f98a82bb7b8c6ae451b905c059eb1e8c&oe=5F7175A4">
      <div class="title">
           Draw
      </div>    
  </div>
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">5</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/12299037_1115951291757226_487763699_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=110&_nc_ohc=5uRQjHsE4AEAX_zZajw&oh=c58382e5f3012b6e8bc698ae2a112293&oe=5F6F0F4F">
      <div class="title">
           3D table 
      </div>   
  </div>
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">6</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/80889716_177138893664311_3114893289016412030_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=111&_nc_ohc=rmC1taLDo9oAX_RFtXR&oh=ed30e253afa25ef4aa38557e3f57e40b&oe=5F6FDE56">
      <div class="title">
           Mask search
      </div>   
  </div>
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">7</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/13126889_210201399365180_922021417_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=Twm7Ef50NyMAX9F6fYU&oh=7d06900a937f72f3fe99b55cb564c605&oe=5F709684">
      <div class="title">
           Lines
      </div>   
  </div>
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">8</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/26871649_1974856766166706_595456387631284224_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=110&_nc_ohc=EPtSVvQWX7sAX_EAXWd&oh=78ba051e57f0c4d5cf4d666133e9c26e&oe=5F6F1F74">
      <div class="title">
           Brother
      </div>   
  </div>
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">9</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/30841816_1601177606646754_7608513596833660928_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=110&_nc_ohc=beqzT89WF_MAX_jZOrT&oh=284d72126c1a4a009df17eb8f1bc3b4e&oe=5F714F21">
      <div class="title">
           Display
      </div>   
  </div>
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">10</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/74666962_771575516643056_3608361156276665108_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=-31DW6kwADEAX-gO58h&oh=aac026c26cb1539b62d0b696d008ae0a&oe=5F71EFC6">
      <div class="title">
           At work
      </div>   
  </div>
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">11</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/66907053_141754330253890_2856071181193144578_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=110&_nc_ohc=GKJr4aCSjR8AX-YEOp7&oh=839ae9597c07a02addc7d7f28647b9ee&oe=5F709C32">
      <div class="title">
           Lines #2
      </div>   
  </div>
    
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- number of the item -->
    <div class="item-number">12</div> 
    <!-- image -->
    <img src="https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/61424547_345090816039122_8009625366607578307_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=dxHlI1km_NMAX9f09Ix&oh=f63dd6182fc408f3afad9d185854ecee&oe=5F7238EA">
    <!-- title if title -->  
    <div class="title">
        The photography are from my instagram
        <p class="french">Les photographies sont visibles sur mon insta</p>
    </div>  
  </div>
    
    <!-- item -->
  <div class="item"> 
    <div class="title">
        Css Masonry
        <p class="french"><a href="https://quentinrenaux.com/category/oneexperimentperday" target="_blank">Check the article</a></p>
    </div>  
  </div>
    
</div>
```

thanks a lot for your help, It's my second question here and sometime it's hard to explain.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: It's the font-size, changing to zero works.